# R shiny selectInput(): multiple option groups not working with one option

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make option groups in `selectInput()`, but seeing the following unexpected result.

If you type the following line in your console:

```
selectInput("test", "I am test", choices = list("Group A" = c("a", "b", "c"), "Group B" = "d"))
```

You should see the following output:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
   <label class="control-label" for="test">I am test</label>
   <div>
      <select id="test">
         <optgroup label="Group A">
            <option value="a" selected>a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
         </optgroup>
         <option value="d">Group B</option>       <====== wrong
      </select>
      <script type="application/json" data-for="test" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the above code is, the `Group B` should be the `optgroup label` instead of `option text`. I imagine the above code should return the following:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
   <label class="control-label" for="test">I am test</label>
   <div>
      <select id="test">
         <optgroup label="Group A">
            <option value="a" selected>a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
         </optgroup>
         <optgroup label="Group B">            <====== correct
            <option value="d">d</option>       <====== correct
         </optgroup>                           <====== correct
      </select>
      <script type="application/json" data-for="test" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this expected? If not, how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your `Group B` choice in a list to get the output you want:

```
selectInput("test", "I am test", choices = list("Group A" = c("a", "b", "c"), "Group B" = list("d")))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just an add-on, if the options are extracted from other source, and you do not know how many options you will get, you can do `as.list` to make sure each option is a list item. e.g., `"Group B" = as.list(levels(iris$Species))`.